# What is the function of springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin configuration/apiDocsUrl?

Tags: java, spring, maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm running the springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin, with the following (standard) configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The plugin appears to run, but there is no output.

I am getting a 404 error in the Maven output:

```
[INFO] --- springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin:0.2:generate (integration-test) @ paatinc-util-websrv ---
10:40:33.930 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
10:40:33.931 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
10:40:33.956 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 25 ms
10:40:33.969 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  io.paat.util.filter.LoggingFilter - GET http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs from 127.0.0.1
[ERROR] An error has occured: Response code 404
```

I can see from my log that the 404 is on a call to: http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs

I also see in the springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin docs the following configuration:

```
 <configuration>
  <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
  <outputFileName>openapi.json</outputFileName>
  <outputDir>/home/springdoc/maven-output</outputDir>
 </configuration>
```

So, it appears that the plugin is attempting to open the local server during integration tests and is failing. What is the point of this? I thought that the plugin would read though my source files and generate an openapi.json file. Why does it need to make an HTTP connection to /v3/api-docs?

Comment: "*I thought that the plugin would read though my source files and generate an openapi.json file.*" - Nope. The plugin starts the app and tries to access an URL of the app where the `application.json` is supposed to reside. My guess is that they took the stance of "someone else generated the `application.json`, we do not have to  re-create it. We just start the server and fetch it".

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know how I can generate just the openapi.json file for my SpringBoot app via Maven?

Comment: Nope. But let me know if you find out =) I have the same problem.

Comment: It says explicitly "The aim of springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin is to generate json and yaml OpenAPI description during build time." It doesn't make sense that it expects to read it from somewhere.

Comment: @Turing85 I figured it out. Here is my project which demonstrates how to generate the openapi.json via Maven at build time: https://github.com/kbaynes/springdoc-maven-plugin-demo. I just had the dependencies wrong.

Comment: There is no shame in answering your own question. Out of curiosity: can you point me to the changes that were necessary? It still looks like the server is started through the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

Comment: For me the problem was that I had removed the 'springdoc-openapi-core' dep. I don't understand why the server still runs, though I think it has something to do with the triggering the plugin to run as part of 'integration tests'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205467/discussion-between-turing85-and-kevinb).

Comment: @KevinB did you solve it, and if yes how? I am having exactly the same issue here.

Comment: I've tried your solution (I was mission the core dependency also) but seems the server it's still needed to be up and running which is not "compile time". Were you able to manage it?

Answer (score 9):

By using **springdoc-openapi-ui** you generate the documentation (html, json & yaml) at **runtime**, when your app is deployed.

In some scenarios you may want to have the documentation at build time, and that's what the **springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin** is for. In order for it to work you need as well to have your application started using spring-boot during the integration phase, as [explained in the documentation](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin).

Comment: That's exactly the thing - the documentation is lying about being generated at build time. Everything is generated at runtime and fetched via http.

Comment: Yeah I'm still getting this even when I follow the instructions and use the spring boot maven plugin to run the app beforehand.

Comment: yeah, this is not technically generated at build time, but at run time (as integration-test phase requires a running server I presume they thought this was ideal time to do it).  not ideal if you don't want integration tests running. I used springdoc-openapi instead and works a treat

Answer (score 5):

Both [diegomtassis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2260761/diegomtassis) & [Erdinc Ay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527942/erdinc-ay) together with [this great baeldung post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation) got me on the right track.

The thing about the [springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin) is: **it isn't able to successfully run on it's own** - nor does it suffice to simply add it as the only dependency to your `pom.xml`!

The plugin needs **2 other dependencies to do the groundwork** in order to make it work:

1. You need to add the **[springdoc-openapi-ui](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi)** plugin (for Tomcat / Spring MVC based apps) **OR** the **[springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi#spring-webflux-support-with-annotated-controllers)** plugin (for Reactive WebFlux / Netty based apps) to your `pom.xml` first!

Here's the Spring MVC example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

2. You need to **configure the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to fire up our Spring Boot app including the API url the `springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin` needs to generate the `openapi.json`** inside the Maven integration test phase.

Here's the needed configuration of the already present `spring-boot-maven-plugin` inside your `pom.xml` (and no: you don't need a version for this plugin here, since it's inheritet from the `spring-boot-starter-parent` you use):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[As the docs state](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin) you can customize things like `apiDocsUrl`, `outputDir` where the `openapi.json` will be placed - and even the name of the json file with `outputFileName`. **But you don't need to do so** (in contrast to what [Peeve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10990503/peeve) said)!

Now if you run Maven using `mvn verify` (or `mvn verify -DskipTests=true` to speed up the execution), you should see some output like that:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.5.RELEASE:start (pre-integration-test) @ hellobackend ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.5.RELEASE)

2020-11-04 10:26:07.246  INFO 42143 --- [           main] i.j.s.SpringBootBuildpackApplication     : Starting SpringBootBuildpackApplication on PikeBook.fritz.box with PID 42143 (/Users/jonashecht/dev/spring-boot/spring-boot-kong/hellobackend/target/classes started by jonashecht in /Users/jonashecht/dev/spring-boot/spring-boot-kong/hellobackend)
2020-11-04 10:26:07.249  INFO 42143 --- [           main] i.j.s.SpringBootBuildpackApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-11-04 10:26:08.730  INFO 42143 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080
2020-11-04 10:26:08.742  INFO 42143 --- [           main] i.j.s.SpringBootBuildpackApplication     : Started SpringBootBuildpackApplication in 1.82 seconds (JVM running for 2.318)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin:1.1:generate (default) @ hellobackend ---
2020-11-04 10:26:09.579  INFO 42143 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource  : Init duration for springdoc-openapi is: 29 ms
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.5.RELEASE:stop (post-integration-test) @ hellobackend ---
[INFO] Stopping application...
2020-11-04 10:26:09.661  INFO 42143 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application shutdown requested.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  23.392 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-04T10:26:11+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Finally you should have a new file `openapi.json` inside your Spring Boot app's `/target` folder like this (which was the point of using the springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin in the first place).
If you like to see a fully comprehensible example project, you can have a look at this one: https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-openapi-kong/tree/main/weatherbackend

Comment: great post, thanks for the analysis!

Answer (score 1):

**First add this Maven dependency to your project**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Secondly make the Maven plugin runnable**:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputFileName>openapi.json</outputFileName>
                <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/openapi-spec</outputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okey guys, so the answer is that this plugins tryies to enable your spring servlet to download the openapi json from it during the compile time. My problem was, that I did not set the proper url for the openapi plugin and therefore 404 error.

The log from issue author:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
10:40:33.956 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 25 ms
10:40:33.969 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  io.paat.util.filter.LoggingFilter - GET http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs from 127.0.0.1
[ERROR] An error has occured: Response code 404
```

The trick is to set the correct url for the json in plugin configurations. It is the url where your json would be at run time (aka when server is running, so change the url, port or whatever you need):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <apiDocsUrl>${url.docs}</apiDocsUrl>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: The first sentence of you answer is right. But then it could mislead people, since the default URL the [springdoc-openapi plugin](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi) generates to serve the API live documentation is `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs` [according to the docs](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin#custom-settings-of-the-springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin). So you only need to configure `apiDocsUrl`, if you changed the configuration of the `springdoc-openapi plugin` beforehand.

Comment: No, other possibilty is that you dont run the application on 8080 as default and then you need to change apiDocsUrl. The guy got 404 error, therfore the openapi.json was not served on the mentioned adress at compile time. So he do needs to change the apiDocsUrl as I said to "where your json would be at run time".

Comment: But as both the authors and your logs show the app runs on `8080` ;) And he also asked for a "standard" configuration. If you use start.spring.io to generate an app skeleton, you get it with an empty `application.properties` file - so no different port! The real answer to the question is that you need to configure 2 additional maven plugins in order to get the `springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin` to work (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64677754/4964553).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had property in application.yaml

`servlet.context-path: /api/v1`

And I needed to add this param in plugin

`<apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/api/v1/v3/api-docs.yaml</apiDocsUrl>`

Or remove property
`servlet.context-path: /api/v1`